# Installing Go packages in non-default directories

Tags: go

I've created an API in Go in which I've installed two packages via `go get` and have created four others for my own use. Everything seems to work fine. However I would like to move where the packages are so that I can have everything within my Git directory.

From what I've read, it should be as easy as changing my `GOPATH` variable to the new directory, and running `go get` again to test. Is this correct? If it is, am I doing anything wrong? Below is what shows in the terminal (Mac OS X) when I run `go env`. If any other info would be useful, please let me know. Thanks.

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-common"
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/git/cbi/api"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

I should clarify that by default my `GOPATH` was an empty string. I tried updating it to the directory above since that is where I wish new packages be installed, and also for Go to look for any packages I've created an placed there.

I'm setting my `GOPATH` variable by running:

```
export GOPATH="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/git/cbi/api"
```

After doing this, I can see the variable has been set when I type `go env`.  However if I quit Terminal and then open it back up, and run `go env` again, the `GOPATH` variable is not set. Is there a reason it's not saving? Should I be setting it another way instead of export?

Comment: What happens when you try to build/run from the new location?

Comment: you haven't given enough information yet. Did you have a problem when you used a different gopath that you need help debugging?

Comment: @RichChurcher I can build and run the go file containing my main function as long as the packages are in my GOROOT directory.  However, if I remove them from there and try to put them under my api directory they aren't found.  And when I try to do a "go install" with a pkg I get: go install: no install location for _PACKAGE_PATH

Comment: @JeremyWall The problem is when I try to use an alternative GOPATH.  It always uses GOROOT

Comment: you need to add the environment variable to your bash config files to make it persistent. usually .bashrc is the file to edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't set the GOPATH variable, the packages will be installed in the GOROOT which is not recommended. If you want to set GOPATH to "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/git/cbi/api", make sure the directory of your code is put in "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/git/cbi/api/src/".

```
However if I quit Terminal and then open it back up, and run "go env" again, the GOPATH variable is not set.
```

Like jeremy says, you should set the environment variable in bash configure file. In mac os, add this to your $HOME/.profile  :
`export GOPATH=/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/git/cbi/api` . 
BTW, you can specify multiple GOPATH, for exmple, `export GOPATH=/path/to/gopath1:/path/to/gopath2`

Comment: After looking more into it, I believe this was the correct answer.  I think me adding the folder per Joe's suggestion was just a coincidence.

Answer (score 2):

My approach has been to start a new Go project by putting the following into env.sh in my project dir

```
export GOPATH=$PWD
export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH
```

Then I always 'source' this file before I start work in a new terminal window, i.e.

```
. env.sh
```

Then when I use 'go get', it puts all the downloaded source code into the current project folder and I can commit it to my chosen version control system. This is the advantage of this approach: everything is held in one directory tree which can easily be versioned.

If I should happen to forget to source env.sh, Go commands usually fail immediately because I don't have write access to /usr/local/go files, which is the default place for them to be put. So I soon found I didn't forget.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure GOPATH have three subfolder:src,pkg/linux_amd64(this one has to do with the OS),bin

More details can refer: [GOPATH](http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/GOPATH) and [Build](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/)

Comment: I didn't have the linux_amd64 folder underneath pkg.  However I added darwin_amd64 since I'm on MAC OS X.  Didn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: Yes, your pkg is right. Does it still report: go install: no install location for _PACKAGE_PATH?

Comment: you don't have to set the darwin_amd64 directory yourself. the go tool will add that automatically when go install something. You only have to add the top level src/ pkg/ bin/ directories.

Comment: I saw this was down-voted, but this seemed to solve the problem for me.  Is there a reason why Go wouldn't create the directory automatically?